# Ramadan and ramadhan tags should be merged

Tags: discussion, tag

Is there a way to flag tags for merging? I don't really want to open up a meta question every time to request a tag merger.

Comment: [meta-tag:bug] tag is for reporting software bugs to SE.

Comment: User with high enough reputation can directly do that. You can start one question title tag merges and then every time you want to suggest a tag merge you can post it as an answer to that question.

Answer (score 4):

I have merged and synonymed the [ramadan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramadan) and [ramadhan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramadhan) tags.

(Beta) Users with 1,250 reputation can [propose tag synonyms](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) if they are considered to have sufficient expertise in that tag (i.e. have an answer score of at least 5 in that tag), and other users with similar expertise can vote on it.  As far as I know, this doesn't actually push a notification/flag to anyone, requiring users (and moderators) to actually check the proposed synonyms list manually for new additions and vote accordingly.  If approved, the tag will be synonymed (merging is, as far as I know, a moderator-only ability).

I do [check the list](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) on occasion and approve anything that I consider a no-brainer, but given how rarely any non-moderators even use the tag synonym interface it's not something I do regularly.  For any tag pairs that aren't no-brainers (i.e. perfect synonyms), bringing it up on meta for community discussion is still preferable.